# filtering problem in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var query = from d in testPersons.person
            where d.Name == txtbox
            select d;
```

`txtbox` is text box on View page.

> How change this code to return all
>   names who starts with any part of
>   name?

For example: When I type R in text box, on View page, this query should return all names who is start with  character R

Comment: I guess that with "txtbox is text box on View page." you mean: There is an input formelement of type text on the view that has the name txtbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx).

```
var query = from d in testPersons.person
            where d.Name.StartsWith(txtbox)
            select d;
```

As long as `Name` is of type String you can do all string operations such as:

- Contains
- EndsWith
- Equals
- And many more..

Here are some more examples and information about [LINQ and Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397915.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a slightly different interpretation of:

*How change this code to return all names who starts with any part of name?*

If you wished to retrieve a person whos first, middle or last names began with the letter typed in *txtbox* you could use:

```
var query = from d in testPersons.person
            where d.Name.StartsWith(txtbox) || d.Name.Contains(" " + txtbox)
            select d;
```